# Issue with rcParams figure.autolayout

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend

Since I am using the rcParams autolayout, my legend is being cutoff when saving the plot to my desktop. I have to outsource my legend because it would cover half of my barplot. This is what my code looks like:

```
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
someplot.plot.bar(figsize=(15,7.5),width=0.8, linewidth=0.9,alpha=0.5,color = "green" ,align = 'center', label='Non-fossil CO2')

plt.xlabel('Country (2014)')
plt.ylabel('kg Co2-Eq / capita')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.105, 1))
plt.savefig('/Users/Pupu/Desktop/popuincineration1.png', format='png', dpi=500)
```

1) How can I avoid that?

2) How can I make the auto layout default again? When typing False, my plots are destroyed completely.

Thanks

Comment: `figure.autolayout` (and also `plt.tight_layout()`) only considers titles, ticklabels and axis labels when repositioning things. So you'll probably have to manually add space for your legend, e.g. with `plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)`

Comment: I tried `plt.subplots_adjust(right = 2)` already and the resulting png file shows only half of the plot.

Comment: The subplot params need to be between 0 and 1 for the subplot to be within the figure. Since the default parameter for `autolayout` is `False`, it cannot destroy anything. Mind that you need to provide a [mcve] if you want debugging help.